# Close a specific application on form close

Tags: vb.net

I am making a simple Anticheat for my game currently, but I am fairly new to VB coding and I have researched on how to be able to close an external application when my form is closed. I currently don't have any code for this since I don't really know how to start. help is much appreciated ! thanks

Comment: `Process.GetProcessesByName(name_of_external_process)` - this will get a collection of processes that match the name you provided. Then you can call `CloseMainWindow` on the process  to request closure or `Kill` to force close it. After which call `Dispose` to dispose of the process object. If you call `CloseMainWindow`, you should add a delay between that call and `Dispose` to give the process time to exit.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Sub CloseProcess(processName as String)
    'FirstOrDefault will get the first process in the list if it exists
    Dim myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault()

    If myProcess Is Nothing Then Return

    myProcess.CloseMainWindow()    'Request closure
    myProcess.WaitForExit(5000)    'Wait 5 seconds for closure

    If Not myProcess.HasExited Then myProcess.Kill() 'Forcefully kill if not yet closed

    myProcess.Dispose() 'Dispose
End Sub
```

```vb
Public Sub CloseProcess(processName as String)
    'Store the full list of returned processes matching the given name
    Dim allProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)

    For Each proc in allProcesses
        proc.CloseMainWindow()    'Request closure
        proc.WaitForExit(5000)    'Wait 5 seconds for closure

        If Not proc.HasExited Then proc.Kill() 'Forcefully kill if not yet closed

        proc.Dispose() 'Dispose
    Next
End Sub
```